# Remove unnecessary control character when exporting record to Excel to SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, excel, ntext

I am currently doing system decom for a ASP.NET system and plan to have all the system data stored in Excel file. The challenge I face is that there is a column of `ntext` data type and the data is split up into mutiple row when exporting to Excel.
I have tried by removing all control characters as per below. But it is still split up into multiple row. Can anyone help? The system is currently using SQL Server 2012.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
    (cast(p.bp_comment as nvarchar(max)), CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(11), '') , CHAR(12), '') , CHAR(13), '') 
    , CHAR(14), '') , CHAR(15), '') , CHAR(16), '') , CHAR(17), '') , CHAR(18), '') , CHAR(19), '') , CHAR(20), '') 
    , CHAR(21), '') , CHAR(22), '') , CHAR(23), '') , CHAR(24), '') , CHAR(25), '') , CHAR(26), '') , CHAR(27), '') 
    , CHAR(28), '') , CHAR(29), '') , CHAR(30), '') , CHAR(31), '') 
    , CHAR(1), '') , CHAR(2), '') , CHAR(3), '') , CHAR(4), '') , CHAR(5), '') , CHAR(6), '') , CHAR(7), '') 
    , CHAR(8), '') , '\n', ''), '\r', '') as [Comment],
```

To remove all control character especially newline and carriage return via SQL using SQL Server DBMS.

Comment: You could try adding char(0) to your script.

Comment: Well if it's `ntext` have you considered some of the other possibilities? U+0085 Next Line? U+2028 Line Separator? U+2029 Paragraph Separator? Or maybe just that Excel still has a lot of legacy limits around 255 characters and a total limit of 32767 characters per cell.

Comment: Why would you use excel for any kind of structured storage?

Comment: It is a comment field but it was misused for picture and big data storage. I previously thought that storing the data to excel is an good option for there is no need for upgrading of OS, DBMS and etc..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sterner,AlwaysLearning and siggemannen.
I have found the root cause for this.It is due to maximum character in a cell for Excel 365 is 32,767.The comment fields that exceeds this length will be split up to multiple row.Attahced is the link for the documentation of Excel 365 [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#ID0EBABAAA=Excel_2016-2013)